# Probability of at least one set of three consecutive equal numbers out of 24 random numbers

Tags: probability

Imagine we have 24 integers chosen uniformly and independently from 0 to 255 (so 256 possible numbers). We write them down in the order that we generate them and then ask "what is the probability that there is at least one run of at least 3 consecutive numbers which are all equal?". How can I calculate this?

This question came up in some work that I'm doing and I'm getting confused about whether certain events are independent.

If we consider the simpler question about pairs of equal consecutive integers then we see

$$\begin{align}
& P(\mbox{at least one equal pair})\\
&=1-P(\mbox{no equal pairs})\\
&= 1-P(\mbox{each of the 23 possible pairs are not equal})\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{256}\right)^{23}
\end{align}$$

where we have used the fact that two pairs being equal are independent (i.e. if we represent the first three numbers by $a,b$ and $c$ we see that whether $a\neq b$ is independent of whether $b\neq c$.)

Can we do the same kind of thing for the case of consecutive triples?

Comment: No, in the case of runs of length at least $3$ there is no such independence. Is this the answer to your question, or you are still seeking how to solve the problem using another approach?

Comment: Thanks for that @Hoda, I would be very interested in any other approaches to solving the problem.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to include a method that gives an estimate over $3000$ times closer to the correct answer than the independence-approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be almost independent-the error will be quite small.  The chance you get three in a row is $\frac 1{256^2}$ and you have $22$ tries, so the chance will be close to $1-\left(1-\frac 1{256^2}\right)^{22}\approx 0.00033564$ per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%281-1/%28256%5E2%29%29%5E22)  This is very close to $\frac {22}{256^2}$

To do it right, we can set up a linked recurrence.  Let
A(n) be the number of sequences of $n$ numbers without a run of $3$ consecutive matching numbers and the last two numbers distinct
B(n) be the number of sequences of $n$ numbers without a run of $3$ consecutive matching numbers and the last two numbers the same
C(n) be the number of sequences of $n$ numbers with a run of $3$ consecutive matching numbers

Then $A(1)=256,B(1)=0,C(1)=0\\A(n)=255A(n-1)+255B(n-1)\\B(n)=A(n-1)\\C(n)=256C(n-1)+B(n-1)$

and you want $\frac {C(24)}{256^{24}}$

The final result is $\frac {2099048725705587959327956073678229730993468326534512896}{2^{192}}\approx 0.00033440$  This is very close to the simplistic answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the probability that in a random string of length $24$ generated uniformly from a $256$-letter alphabet, no letter occurs more than twice consecutively. (Actually you want the complement of this event, but this is easier to talk about.)

As you say you're getting confused about independence and the like, let's just count the *number* of such good strings, and divide by the total number of possible strings (which is $256^{24}$). This lets us be finished with the *probability* part of the problem.

Now, for the simpler no-letter-twice-consecutively case, we could just count the number of strings as $256 \times 255 \times 255 \times \dots = 256 \times (255)^{23}$ (as there are all the $256$ choices for the first letter, but then for each of the later $23$ letters, it can't be the previous one, so only $256-1$ choices).

Here, whether a letter is allowed at a particular position or not depends on the previous *two* letters. So, let's define $S_n$ and $D_n$ as the number of $n$-letter words (over the $256$-letter alphabet) such that no letter occurs thrice consecutively, and the last two letters are the **same** or **different**, respectively.

We have the recurrence relations

- $S_n = D_{n-1}$ (take any word of length $n-1$ with last two letters distinct, and append the last letter again)
- $D_n = (S_{n-1} + D_{n-1}) \times 255$ (take *any* word of $n-1$ letters, and append a letter different from the last one)
- and the initial conditions $S_2 = 256$ and $D_2 = 256 \times 255$.

Using the first one to write everything in terms of the $D$s, the recurrence relations become
$$\begin{align}
D_1 &= 256 \\
D_2 &= 256 \times 255 \\
D_n &= (D_{n-1} + D_{n-2}) \times 255 \quad \text{for }n > 2
\end{align}$$

We can iterate this to get $D_{24}$ and $S_{24} = D_{23}$, and the answer you want (probability at least one block of three equal characters) will be
$$1 - \frac{D_{24} + S_{24}}{256^{24}}.$$

Calculating this by computer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
d = {1: 256, 2: 256 * 255}
def D(n):
  if n in d: return d[n]
  d[n] = (D(n - 1) + D(n - 2)) * 255
  return d[n]

numerator = D(24) + D(23)
print numerator, 256**24 - numerator
```

shows that the answer is
$$1 - \frac{6275002686660975175876461467133988186371361976137500000000}{256^{24}} = \frac{2099048725705587959327956073678229730993468326534512896}{256^{24}} \approx .000334$$

---

Alternatively, we can prove that the generating function weighted by probability for all such strings is ([*Analytic Combinatorics*](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html), V.11 p. 312)

$$W^{[2]}(z) = \left(1 - z\frac{1-(z/256)^2}{1-(z/256)^3}\right)^{-1}$$

So the probability you seek is 
$$1 - [z^{24}]W^{[2]}(z).$$

---

Here's a way of avoiding the independence assumption. Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable that the three letters starting at position $i$ are all equal. Clearly, for $1 \le i \le 22$, we have 
$$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \Pr(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{256^2}.$$
So in a random string, the expected *number* $X$ of blocks of three equal letters is
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum_i X_i\right] = \frac{22}{256^2} \approx 0.0003357.$$

As we have
$$E[X] = \sum_{n \ge 1} E[X \ge n]$$
(true for any random variable $X$ taking nonnegative integer values), this $\operatorname{E}[X]$ is an upper bound on the probability $\Pr(X \ge 1)$ of having at least one block of three equal letters. To refine the bound, we can get an estimate of the probability of having two or more blocks (or rather, a better one: right now, we're using the lower bound of $0$).

There are multiple ways in which one can have multiple blocks-of-$3$:

1. A block of equal letters of length $4$. For each $k$ from $1$ to $21$, the probability of the four letters starting at $k$ being equal is $\frac{1}{256^3}$.
2. Two disjoint blocks of $3$. If the ending position of the first block is $k$ (so $k \ge 3$) and the starting position of the second one is $l$ (so $l \le 22$), then for each of the $\binom{20}{2}$ such pairs of blocks determined by some $(k, l)$ both in $[3, 22]$, the probability of that event is $\frac{1}{(256^2)^2}$.
3. Non-disjoint blocks, like a block of length $5$, but we'll ignore them as they have even lower probability that the two above: note that a block of length $5$ actually means three blocks of $3$.

So we can estimate (approximately) $\frac{21}{256^3} + \frac{\binom{20}{2}}{256^4}$ for this. (This is an overcount, as the tiny-probability event of multiple of these happening — basically all of $\Pr(X \ge 3)$ and so on — has been counted twice, but those are of smaller magnitude and we can ignore them for now.)

This estimate gives for us

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(X \ge 1) 
&\approx \operatorname{E}[X] - \Pr(X \ge 2) \\
&\approx \frac{22}{256^2} - \frac{21}{256^3} - \frac{\binom{20}{2}}{256^4}
\end{align}
$$

which ($\mathbf{0.000334397}42$) is much closer to the true answer ($0.00033439775$) than either of the estimates $1-(1-1/256^2)^{22}$ ($\mathbf{0.00033}56$) or $22/256^2$ ($\mathbf{0.00033}569$).